# how to fetch same column from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have tables like below...

A (id,name)
B(id,name)
c(id,name)

now I want to fetch name of each table, such that there will be no cross product table.i.e, total number of rows will not exceed the max rows table.
for exp if data is below

```
  for table A
id     name
1      dilip
2      Amit
3      Piyush
4      sumit

for table B
id     name
1      dilip
4      sumit

for table C
id     name
2      Amit
3      Piyush
```

Then out put should be like below

```
nodename_A     nodename_B     nodename_C
Dilip           Dilip           NULL
Amit            NULL           Amit
Piyush          NULL           Piyush
Sumit           Sumit           NULL
```

In this Table is the base table which will contain all the entries for id and node, but other tables may contain less number of entries or may also contain duplicate entries.

Please tell me how can I do it

Comment: Is tableA guaranteed to be a superset of all possible names or could the others have values that tableA doesn't have?

Comment: Thanks Mike Parkhill , A is base table to contain all the entries of id and name, but other tables not necessarily contain all the entries or may also contain duplicate entries

Answer (score 0):

Use `FULL JOIN` with `COALESCE` in the joins:

```
select nodename_A = A.name
  , nodename_B = B.name
  , nodename_C = C.name
from A
  full join B on A.id = B.id
  full join C on coalesce(A.id, B.id) = C.id
order by coalesce (A.id, B.id, C.id)
```

You can see an example of the code running here:

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60517/2).

OK, based on new comments I'm now assuming:

1. Table A will have **all** the name records.
2. Duplicates may exist in other tables.

This new query will work for the above scenario:

```
select nodename_A = A.name
  , nodenameB = case when exists (select 1 from B where A.id = B.id) then A.name end
  , nodenameC = case when exists (select 1 from C where A.id = C.id) then A.name end
from A
```

[New SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8b88/3), now with duplicates in the data.

Hopefully this works for you now.

Comment: But when I fetch then found number of rows are more then number of rows in largest table

Comment: Have you run the demo above? This returns four rows as expected. Can you please provide more information?

Comment: Did you have any luck resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think a couple of outer joins should do it:

```
Select a.name as aName, b.name as bName, c.name as cName
From A
LEFT join B on a.id = b.id
LEFT join C on a.id = c.id
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike Parkhill, but I have to fetch them on basis of id not name

Comment: Using @Ian Preston's Sql Fiddle I was able to get my above query to provide the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

what about a pivot tricks?

just a differ sollution..

I guess the full outer join solution is more easy to read

anyway..

if you realy want the same name in all columns of each row, or null if doesnt exist

you should do something like this

```
select * 
from(   select name as row
                      ,'Table A' as [table]
                      ,name
                 from [table A]

                union all              
                select name as row
                     ,'Table B' as [table]
                     ,name
                from [Table B]      

               union all 
               select name as row
                    ,'Table C' as [table]
                    ,name
               from [Table C]       
)V
PIVOT(max(v.name) for [table] in ([Table A],[Table B],[Table C]))P
order by row
```

resultset seems like this

```
Table A        Table B       Table C
Dilip           Dilip          NULL
Amit            NULL           Amit
Piyush          NULL           Piyush
Sumit           Sumit          NULL
```

if you just want a list of names on each table,

that equal names dont need to be in same row.. should do something like this

```
select * 
from(   select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by name) as row
                      ,'Table A' as [table]
                      ,name
                 from [table A]

                union all              
                select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by name) as row
                     ,'Table B' as [table]
                     ,name
                from [Table B]      

               union all 
               select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by name) as row
                    ,'Table C' as [table]
                    ,name
               from [Table C]       
)V
PIVOT(max(v.name) for [table] in ([Table A],[Table B],[Table C]))P
order by row
```

resultset seems like this

```
Table A        Table B       Table C
Amit            Dilip          Amit
Dilip           Sumit          Piyush
Piyush          NULL           NULL
Sumit           NULL           NULL
```